# which is faster s+='a' or s=s+'a' in python

Tags: python

```
s=s+'a'
s+='a'
s.append(a)
```

Is there any difference between above three?

I am confused with these choices.

Which needs to be used at what time and is string `append` method faster than the others?

Comment: The second one actually works for you?

Comment: Without knowing what `s` is, it will be impossible to answer anything. Also, the second example is a syntax error.

Comment: You cant do `s.append(a)` on a string.

Comment: If you want to concatenate several strings you should use ''.join([str1,str2,....,strN]).

Comment: use ipython's `%timeit`!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Neither. It's like asking which spoon feeds faster? silver or plastic? Neither, it's up to the person who uses it.

In other words this is inapplicable to a language. A language simply talks about grammar and semantics but not about speed i.e. it specifies ways of expressing something and its grammar, not how fast it is done.

Speed is a parameter of an [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_implementation) not [language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language); know the difference. An implementation may treat both `s += 'a'` and `s = s + 'a'` similarly underneath (so there's no difference between the two on such an implementation) but another implementation can implement one faster over the other. So when talking about speed/efficiency/performance, it's vital to specify what implementation, platform, compiler, etc. is being used.

[CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython/), [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), etc. are implementations of the [Python language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), again their speed in performing such expressions may vary based on the compiler, platform, etc. Measure, don't speculate!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `s` is a string, the time required seems to be identical:

```
$ python -m timeit 's="x"; s+="x"'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0607 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 's="x"; s=s+"x"'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0607 usec per loop
```

Also, string objects to not have an `append()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run the test time yourself, and check:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("s=''; s+='a'", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit("s=''; s=s+'a'", number=10000))
```

Both give similar result:

```
0.000557306000700919
0.0005544929990719538
```

Comment: thank you Marcin
but what about append()

Comment: @TirupatiRao You cant do `append` on  a string.

Comment: ok thank you .
what about other sequence data type ?

Comment: @TirupatiRao Just use timeit, to test them in the similar fashion as seen here.

Answer (score -2):

```
  s= s+'a'

  s += 'a'

  s.append(a)
```

Have a look on http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

s.append(a)  is faster among these. Then s needs to be a string list.

Comment: you cant do `append` on a string. So how it can be faster?

Comment: There is no string append method. It is a list append method in the link you have given which then uses string's join method to form a string

Comment: Yes, we cant. 
`def method4():
   str_list = []
   for num in xrange(loop_count):
     str_list.append(`num`)
   return ''.join(str_list)`