# In python, why is s*3 faster than s+s+s?

Tags: python, string, operators

I was going through the google's python intro and came across the statement that `s * 3` is faster than doing `s + s + s` where `s` is of type `string`.

Any reason for that to happen?

I googled and found [which is faster s+='a' or s=s+'a' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287428/which-is-faster-s-a-or-s-sa-in-python). But that didn't help

Comment: well, I would say the former is a single specific operation, whereas the latter is made of two separate operations, and the second one would do what the first one had done already (e.g. inspect the string)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `s * 3` is one operation, whereas `s + s + s` is two operations; it's really `(s + s) + s`, creating an additional string object that then gets discarded.

You can see the difference by using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to look at the bytecode each generates:

`s + s + s`:

```
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             10 BINARY_ADD          
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

`s * 3`:

```
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also test it yourself here:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("string=''; string='s'+'s'+'s'", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit("string2=''; string2='s'*3", number=10000))
```

My guess is that `s*3` treats it as one operation vs. two with `s+s+s`.